# Manjaro 18 (Arch) Installing Packages Outside Repository

Tags: package-management, manjaro, source, pacman

So I recently switched to Manjaro. I am having an issue with installing MegaSync from mega.nz. When I download their package for Arch it gives me a .tar.xz file. I'm not familiar with .xz but it's an archive so I go ahead and unarchive it. I see a /usr and /etc folder with stuff that looks like source compilation files. However looking under /usr I see that there is a megasync executable file. I found this forum on installing packages outside the repositories in Arch:

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/installing-from-tar-tar-gz/8070

Apparently according to one user on there installing outside repositories is taboo in Arch... which is odd. I come from using Debian/RHEL distros. Never had a situation where you were inhibited from doing this. At least not with some configuration being put in place beforehand. Regardless I looked further tried the typical .configure, make, install. Still nothing.

Am I missing something with how to use pacman? Or am I just that rusty when it comes from installing from source?

Answer (score 0):

So my thoughts were correct and it just took a while to find:

https://cloudcone.com/docs/article/installing-packages-from-source-in-arch-linux/

pacman -U (package_name).tar.xz

megasync is now installed and working perfectly.